# Hiding UIImageView from UISwitch action in popover (iPad)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, uiswitch

I need to hide an UIImageView, from an action triggered by a UISwitch which is inside a popover.

I'm using this piece of code however it does nothing when tapping the UISwitch, probably because the UISwitch its inside a popover view.

This code works perfectly on iPhone, however on iPad does not work and the UIImageView does not hide. Why?

```
- (IBAction)toggleImage:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isOn]){
        self.myImage.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        self.myImage.hidden = YES;
    }
}
```

UIImageView is connected to an outlet and UISwitch is connected to an outlet and action.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Strangely, NSLog(@"%@",self.myImage); outputs null. 
However in Interface Builder appears as connected?

Comment: See this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller/1622312-passthroughviews

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I link that specific UIImageView to '@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray<UIView *> *passthroughViews;' ?

Comment: Can you tell a little about how the views are arranged? Are both the switch and the imageview not on the popover, but on an underlying view?

Comment: The imageview is on the main parent view (from the initial ViewController), and the switch its inside a popover which appears when tapping a button.

Answer (score 1):

Since the switch being interacted with is on the popover and the image view that we want to change is on the underlying (presenting) VC, the proper approach is to make the underlying VC a delegate of the popover.

```
// MyPopoverVC.h
@protocol PopoverDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)popover:(MyPopoverVC *)vc changedSwitchTo:(BOOL)on;
@end

@interface MyPopoverVC : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<PopoverDelegate>delegate;
// ...
@end
```

In the Popover VC's implementation (IMPORTANT: the switch's IBAction should be wired to the popover vc)...

```
- (IBAction)toggleImage:(UISwitch *)sender {
    [self.delegate popover:self changedSwitchTo:sender.on];
}
```

In the presenting vc, declare it as conforming to that `<PopoverDelegate>` protocol. Before presenting the popover, initialize the delegate...

```
MyPopoverVC *myPopoverVC = [[MyPopoverVC alloc] init...
myPopoverVC.delegate = self;
```

Also in the presenting vc, implement the delegate protocol...

```
- (void)popover:(MyPopoverVC *) changedSwitchTo:(BOOL)on {
    self.myImage.hidden = !on;
}
```